# Filter a list and maintain header elements with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I have a data structure -> `List<ItemWithSection>`

```
data class ItemWithSection(
    val Item: Item? = null,
    val section: Section? = null
)
```

This is basically a representation of a list that can have headers and items eg

- Header
- Item
- Item
- Header
- Item
- Item

I want to create a search function which is based on some properties which are inside the Item object. How can I do that but also maintain the existing headers.

What I did until now: 
`list.filter { it.item?.doesContainQuery("p") ?: true }`

The above function will leave in this list the items that matches the query and will not touch the section but I need also the section's correctly displayed.

Comment: *this is basically a representation of a list that can have headers and items* what is the point of `Section` then

Comment: As a wrapper for the UI, this list is used in a RecyclerView for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another solution which doesn't involve changing the data structure. It will filter out the items that doesn't fulfill the query requirements and then it will loop through the list to find two consecutive sections. If it finds any it removes it.

```
        val filteredList = list.filter { it.item?.doesContainQuery(query) ?: true }
        val results = filteredList.toMutableList()

        filteredList.forEachIndexed { index, itemWithSection ->
            val nextItem = filteredList.getOrNull(index + 1) ?: return@forEachIndexed

            if (itemWithSection.isSectionEmpty(nextItem)) {
                results.remove(itemWithSection)
            }
        }
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `Section` class can do, so lets say it looks like following:

```
class Section {
    fun doesFit(p: String): Boolean { ... }
}
```

Then your filter functions can look like:

```
list.filter {
    it.item?.doesContainQuery("p") ?: true && it.section?.doesFit("p") ?: true
}
```

But I think it would be better to put this logic in your `ItemWithSection` class.

```
data class ItemWithSection(val item: Item? = null, val section: Section? = null) {
    fun doesFit() = item?.doesContainQuery("p") ?: true &&
            section?.doesFit("p") ?: true
}
```

And your filter function call will be much shorter:

```
list.filter { it.doesFit() }
```

Or

```
list.filter(ItemWithSection::doesFit)
```

Comment: Section is just a data class. I don't need to filter is based on the query. Item's have headers which they belong to.

Comment: (my opinion) you should restructure your data. Items should not know to which section they belong. Rather a section should know what items it contains

Comment: I agree, it would be a map with <Section, List<Item>> but the problem is that my UI needs a flat list of items like the one in the question.